# LaTeX cross referencing

Tags: latex

I am new to LaTeX.

I have a section named as below in my LaTeX file:

```
\section{acedemic details} \label{sec:relat-work-import}
```

This code produces output as below:

> II. academic details

I am using this `\S\ref{sec:relat-work-import}` to refer to the above section elsewhere in my article, which produces "$II".

I would like to know: Is it possible to get just "II" as output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\S` causes the dollar sign to be output. Simply remove that before the `\ref` and you should get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just leave off the `\S`:

```
\ref{sec:relat-work-import}
```

This should give you just "II".